# Android "Best Practice" use of Intents

Tags: android

I'm an Android newbie so I apologize if this is a dumb question . . .

Intents are essentially messaging objects that can be used to activate 3 kinds of components:  Activities, Services or Applications.

Especially with regard to Activities, are intents always the preferred way to activate an Activity, despite the overhead of constructing an intent object and using the overhead of the built-in Android OS for passing it?

If the Activity in question is known by the programmer to be the only legitimate one to perform a particular activity is it ever acceptable to invoke it by some more direct means such as a direct invocation via a method call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really disagree with people voting it down, that's why I voted it up to 0 again. It's clear that this guy is just curious. Think of this as "academic". I use Intents all the time and never thought about it. But curiosity is what drives innovators... I would be interested in the outcome of this answer, even if just to know about it, not to use it (Intents are clearly the proper way to go). Thinking outside the box is always a good thing. It doesn't mean that doing outside the box is a good thing though. Maybe if this guy had 200k reputation we would all see this as a "researcher question"?

Comment: Couldn't agree more. A perfectly valid question imho. Especially among all the other "pls help me solve my school assignment so I don't have to look for the answer myself"-questions that keeps flooding in.

Comment: My points exactly, Fredrik... kudos for you, too. We all need more thinkers, not copiers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> despite the overhead of constructing
>   an intent object and using the
>   overhead of the built-in Android OS
>   for passing it?

The intent object is pretty simple, it is the last thing you should worry about when you think for "overhead"

> direct invocation via a method call?

It just won't work out, Android is a framework it is not just a pile of classes, it is like trying to use the constructor of an Activity.

But why do you have something against the Intents, why you decided that they should be "workaround" , and not the Toast.makeText or whatever ?

Comment: Why do you think I have anything "against" it?  I was having this discussion with 2 other equally newbie Android programmers and one of them asked this and I realized I had no idea so I volunteered to post the question here.

Comment: ... keep in mind that the main Google website for Android development says that StackOverflow is where we newbies are supposed to go to ask questions, so don't get mad at us for asking beginner questions!

Comment: Hey @Peter Nelson, calm down, I am not "mad" or whatever, you are saying that because of the "against" word, I asked you this as a normal question, to see why you choose exactly Intents as a "overhead", and I expected an answer from you based on which I could edit my post and add additional info in it. And I used "against" because it is "against" - since you ask if you can NOT use them, this means that you have something against them. So, I waited for a comment, but I guess you just got mad, lol :)

Comment: The bottom line appears to be that using intents is the correct "best practice" (or maybe the only way) for activating those components.  I'll point my 2 coworkers at this thread so they can see for themselves.   I'm marking the question "answered".

Comment: @PeterNelson Yours is a great question. I really appreciate your asking it: the system seems to be gratuitously complicated. I'm trying to use `startActivityForResult` to get a result back. It's quite a bit of rigmarole for what seems could be just a simple method/function call. To get *y* = *f(x*), with Android we've got to use intents (a few lines) to pass the *x* and `@Override public void onActivityResult(...)...` (several lines) to receive the *y*. **More lines = more debugging.** (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) Why couldn't the folks behind Android have made this process more straight-forward for developers? What is it about Android activities that makes it necessary to use this complicated framework?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, and somebody please correct me if I am wrong here, the only way to start another Activity is by using an Intent.